# How to update values in related object fields after record is deleted

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger

I have two objects ObjA__c and ObjB__c which are in many-many relation. Now there is a field on ObjA__c which is sum__c and this value is a sum of rank__c field on ObjB__c.

For ex:
If ObjA__c has 3 related records of ObjB__c then sum__c on ObjA__c is equal to the sum of rank__c on ObjB__c.

This value sum__c should auto update for all inserts/updates/deletes

I have written Trigger on ObjB__c to handle this and this works fine for inserts and updates but not working for deletes.

```
trigger newTrigger on ObjB__c (before insert, after insert, after update, after delete) {



//Update logic

     if(trigger.isUpdate && trigger.isAfter){
            for(ObjB__c updateRec : trigger.new){
                System.debug('update record Id:::'+ updateRec.Id);
                List<ObjA__c> objARecords = [SELECT sum__c, ObjB__c, ObjB__r.rank WHERE ObjA__c =: updateRec.Id];
                System.debug('objARecords.size:::'+ objARecords.size());
                List<ObjA__c> objAList = new List<ObjA__c>();
                // logic to handle summation
                for(ObjA__c obA: objARecords){
                     ObjA__c objecta = new ObjA__c();
                      objecta.sum__c += obA.ObjB__r.rank;
                      objAList.add(objecta);
              }
            }
             update objAList;
}
   //Delete logic

    if(trigger.isDelete && trigger.isAfter){
            for(ObjB__c deleteNetworkRecord : trigger.old){
                System.debug('delete record Id:::'+ deleteNetworkRecord.Id);
                List<ObjA__c> objARecords = [SELECT sum__c, ObjB__c, ObjB__r.rank WHERE ObjA__c =: deleteNetworkRecord.Id];
                System.debug('objARecords.size:::'+ objARecords.size());
                // logic to handle summation
            }
        }
    }
```

Expected:
ObjA__c with 3 ObjB__c records each having rank__c values as 2, 3, 4 respectively. So sum__c = 9.
If second record of ObjB__c is deleted then rank__c values is 2, 4 respectively, then sum__c should become 6

My delete logic is giving me the delete recordId but since the records are already deleted the size() is returning 0 and no update is happening.
How to handle delete in this situation, if I use beforeDelete, the sum will still hold the value of deleted record , if I write afterDelete, values are not populating based on the recordId of deleted record. Please help me with a soolution to handle this in my trigger.

Comment: note that if you used DLRS, it would avoid the need for a trigger entirely and handles deletes/inserts/updates

Answer (score 0):

You can use before context for this scenario. try this

```
if(trigger.isDelete && trigger.isBefore){
  for(ObjB__c deleteNetworkRecord : trigger.old){
      System.debug('delete record Id:::'+ deleteNetworkRecord.Id);
      List<ObjA__c> objARecords = [SELECT sum__c, ObjB__c, ObjB__r.rank WHERE ObjA__c =: deleteNetworkRecord.Id];
     System.debug('objARecords.size:::'+ objARecords.size());
      // logic to handle summation
            }
        }
also update trigger newTrigger on ObjB__c (before insert, after insert, after update, before delete)
```

Comment: Changing it to isBefore is considering the deleted record value also and adding it to the sum. Requirement is, it should omit the deleted record's rank ad sum the other records.

Answer (score 0):

**ObjA__c with 3 ObjB__c records each having rank__c values as 2, 3, 4 respectively. So sum__c = 9. If second record of ObjB__c is deleted then rank__c values is 2, 4 respectively, then sum__c should become 6**

for this scenario used below code it will help to finish your requirement.
**trigger should on after context**.

```
if (Trigger.isDelete) {
            handleDelete(Trigger.old);
        }
    public static void updateSum(List<Id> objAIds) {
        List<ObjectA__c> objARecords = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, rank__c FROM ObjectsB__r) FROM ObjectA__c WHERE Id IN :objAIds];
    
        for (ObjectA__c objA : objARecords) {
            decimal sum = 0;
            for (ObjectB__c objB : objA.ObjectsB__r) {
                sum += objB.rank__c;
            }
            objA.sum__c = sum;
        }
        
        update objARecords;
    }
    private void handleDelete(List<ObjectB__c> deletedRecords) {
        Set<Id> objAIds = new Set<Id>();
        
        for (ObjectB__c objB : deletedRecords) {
            objAIds.add(objB.ObjectA__c);
        }
        
        updateSum(new List<Id>(objAIds));
    }
```

This code is only for delete requirement and it is working fine.
**Result: sum__c = 6;**